# Elegant way to write repeated function

Tags: javascript, jquery, organization

In JS / jQuery there's often a need to do something and then repeat it under certain circumstances.

For example something like this, it's only an example:

```
$(window).load(function() {

scaleSomething();

$(window).resize(function() {
scaleSomething();
});

});
```

What would be the elegant way to write something like this? Because in such situations one function / block of code is always doubled.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `.on` to bind multiple events. Please read [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to know more about it.

Try,

```
$(window).on('load resize',scaleSomething)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can group space-separated events when using ".on" method:

```
$(window).on("load resize", function() {
    scaleSomething();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: The answer is good for this certain context but it's not exactly what I meant. As I said it's an example. I need to think up a better one for the topic...

Comment: Can you give me another example that bothers you the same way so that I could more clearly see your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to trigger the event immediately after you create a listener:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    scaleSomething()
}).trigger('resize');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `on` to attach an event handler to multiple events.  The events are passed as the first argument to the `on` function.  The argument should be a string with event names delimited by spaces.

```
$(window).on("load resize", function(){
   scaleSomething();
});

function scaleSomething(){
   alert("scaling");
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/7ZFpr/